# How should I use the `round() ` function in Cython?

Tags: python, cython

----------Update-------------------------

Found some light [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/cython-users/_rYeUzzeGNk).

> The downside to this is that the official 64-bit Python build does not ship with libmsvcr90.a, which we need to link with the correct C runtime DLL.

-----------Original post-------------------

My Python version:

Python 3.3.5, with MSC v.1600 64 bit in Windows. Windows SDK v7.1 was installed and used. I have been working with Cython for a week and it seems that it runs other code just fine.

In this [link](http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/language_basics.html#compile-time-definitions), it said `round()` is one of the built in functions. However, when I call it in my cython code and use `cython my_code.pyx -a` to check, the function was pure yellow which means the python method was used.

Then I did some googling, and used:

`from libc.math cimport round`

but it said "unresolved external symbol" during compilation.

What should I do?

Here is the code:

```
from libc.math cimport round

cdef float a = 1.5
cdef float b

b = round(a)
print(b)
```

And it said: fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals error

My setup.py:

```
from distutils.core import setup
from distutils.extension import Extension
from Cython.Build import cythonize
import numpy as np

extensions = [
    Extension('test', ['test.pyx'], include_dirs = [np.get_include()]),
    ]

setup(
    ext_modules = cythonize(extensions)
    )
```

I know np.get_include() is really not necessary in this case, but I just added them because I use numpy too often and it wouldn't hurt too much for this case anyway.

My command to compile it:

```
python setup.py build_ext --inplace
```

And the result (I actually used setup1.py on my machine):

X:\WorkFolder\DataAnalysis\lw9pg\mol>python setup1.py build_ext --inplace
running build_ext
building 'test' extension
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\Bin\amd64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /MD /W3 /GS- /DNDEBUG -IX:\WinPython3\python-3.3.5.amd64\include -IX:\WinPython3\python-3.3.5.amd64\include /Tctest.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.3\Release\test.obj
test.c
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\Bin\amd64\link.exe /DLL /nologo /INCREMENTAL:NO /LIBPATH:X:\WinPython3\python-3.3.5.amd64\libs LIBPATH:X:\WinPython3\python-3.3.5.amd64\PCbuild\amd64 /EXPORT:PyInit_test build\temp.win
-amd64-3.3\Release\test.obj /OUT:X:\WorkFolder\DataAnalysis\lw9pg\mol\test.pyd /IMPLIB:build\temp.win-amd64-3.3\Release\
test.lib /MANIFESTFILE:build\temp.win-amd64-3.3\Release\test.pyd.manifest
test.obj : warning LNK4197: export 'PyInit_test' specified multiple times; using first specification
   Creating library build\temp.win-amd64-3.3\Release\test.lib and object build\temp.win-amd64-3.3\Release\test.exp
test.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol round referenced in function   __pyx_pf_4test_rounding
X:\WorkFolder\DataAnalysis\lw9pg\mol\test.pyd : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
error: command '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio   10.0\VC\Bin\amd64\link.exe"' failed with exit status 112
0

Comment: how are you using it?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Thanks for the response! I'll post my code in a minute. I forgot to do that... Sorry.

Comment: so you are compiling exactly what you have posted?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham yes I am. But I haven't tried the ipython magic yet.

Comment: how are you compiling it?

Comment: I'm not sure what the issue is: the docs you linked do say that `round` is available, but the same passage says that `enumerate` and `slice` are too.  Saying a built-in function is available in the namespace isn't the same as there's a C version.

Comment: @DSM Thank you! You are right - I guess it's just the default round() function is not C version. And after talking to Padraic, I think it might be something wrong with my python 3 and 64-bit on windows... Thanks still!

Comment: does it compile without including numpy?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham No it wouldn't ... Thank you so much for helping me debug. I think my environment is having difficulties in finding libc.math (which I don't know why because math.pyd does exist in my cython folder). I am trying to learn the ipython cython magic to see whether it would work... Thank you so much again. I really appreciate your help!

Comment: no problem, you should probably post the tracback along with the error.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I have posted the traceback now... Still fighting for it :(

Comment: did you try using mingw,?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I didn't... For one thing is my python is 64-bit and mingw is 32-bit. PS: I updated my OP, and it seems it is a problem for the 64-bit version of python. Well... Gotta live with it I guess :) Thanks still!

Answer (score 3):

If you want to test simple cython code, the easiest way is using `pyximport`:

To run yours, assuming the file your code is in is called `tester.pyx`:

In the same directory, put this at the top of a python file and just run the file, you will see your `print b` will output `2.0`.

```
import pyximport
pyximport.install()
```

To compile and run a cython function, I use the following setup.py script:

```
from distutils.core import setup
from distutils.extension import Extension
from Cython.Distutils import build_ext

ext= Extension("tester", sources=["tester.pyx"])
setup(ext_modules=[ext],cmdclass={'build_ext': build_ext})
```

Run it on your `.pyx` file with the following command, the `--inplace`  compiles it into the same dir :

```
python setup.py build_ext --inplace --compiler=mingw32 # --compiler=mingw32 only needed on windows
```

You will have a (`tester.pyd`) (tester.so on mac and linux) file where you can import your functions from as if they were coming from a python module.

This is a simple function that rounds a number:

```
from libc.math cimport round

def rounding(float n):
    return round(n)
```

I `compile` it or use `pyxinstall`  importing it and running it like:

```
In [29]: from tester1 import *

In [30]: rounding(12.3453455)
Out[30]: 12.0
```

Using pyximport:

```
In [21]: import pyximport

In [22]: pyximport.install()
Out[22]: (None, None)
         from tester import *
In [23]: rounding(10.23232)
Out[23]: 10.0
```

I created a pure python rounding method to compare:

```
def py_rounding(n):
    return round(n)

import timeit
if __name__=='__main__':
    print timeit.timeit('py_rounding(10.23232)','from cyt import py_rounding')
    print timeit.timeit('rounding(10.23232)','from tester import rounding')
    0.183354854584
    0.037761926651
```

The `cython`  code  is considerably faster.

These are very basic examples, you can find much better uses for cython [here](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/rossant/ipython-minibook/blob/master/chapter5/505-cython-numpy.ipynb)
including using the `%load_ext cythonmagic` using ipython

Comment: Thank you Padraic! I do know how to compile Cython, and your answer seems to indicate that the above code compiles smoothly on your Python... Is that true? I am thinking it is probably something to do with Python 3 and 64-bit on Windows 7. I attached my setup.py on the OP.

Comment: Your code compiles fine for me using python2.7 and 3.4 using my setup.py script, Have you tried using my script or `--complier=mingw32`, I was under the impression it was needed for windows?

Comment: It also compiles fine using your setup.py